# generating function for $0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,\dotsc$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that the generating functions is  $$x + x^4 + x^7 + x^{10} +\dotsb$$
and then we can factor out a $x$ to get 
$$x(1+(x^3) + (x^3)^2 + (x^3)^3 + \dotsb )$$

Now I need my answer in closed form which is the part I do not know how to do. The text book answer is $x/(1-x^3)$, but I'm not sure how they got this.

Comment: When referring to yourself, capitalize the letter i. Also, format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that $$\frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + \cdots,$$ then letting $z = x^3$ immediately results in the desired equality.

Comment: Note for the future: Exploiting $\frac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\cdots$ will come up over and over.